# How do I escalate a Mail UI/usability bug to Apple without having to include sysdiagnose data?

Tags: bug, privacy

I'm trying to file a Mail UI/Usability bug and it won't let me file it without filing a sysdiagnose. I see NO reason that Apple needs that private configuration data for a bug that has nothing to do with my individual machine's configuration.

How do I escalate this issue to Apple without having to include the sysdiagnose data?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question about *why* Apple does something is outside the scope of what can be asked here as defined in the [Help Center](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: I submitted a flag. Sorry haven't posted on Stack Exchange for awhile and wasn't thinking in that context at the time.

Comment: But still, there should be some way to get Apple to solve that. Seriously they should not be requiring sysdiagnose for every bug filing. That seems like a draconian measure if not a ruse to thwart people from filing bugs at all.

Comment: Perhaps reword it to take out the "why" and leave in the "how do I..."

Comment: What  exact venue are you trying this? Developer bug reports are quite different from using e.g.  "Feedback Assistant"?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: Just yesterday, Feedback Assistant urged me to include a full sysdiagnose. Unlike very often previously, I thought it superfluous this time, and forced it to proceed without. But there might be   a different policy at work. Dev-bugs I got answers on feedback back. FA seems like a black hole to me so far.

Comment: I've filed a dozen or dozen and a half bugs over the years. Not sure if any of them have been fixed. Maybe one that was a dupe of something that got a lot of people. They sure don't encourage people to give them product feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the Mail app on macOS, you can submit a bug report via the [Mail feedback page](https://www.apple.com/feedback/mail.html).

In the Feedback Type drop-down list you'll have the option of selecting *Bug Report* as your feedback type. There's also a *Design/Ease of Use* option that may be relevant in your case.

You can also access Apple's main [Product Feedback page](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) if your feedback is about something else.

Comment: That's great! Thanks. Didn't know about that. For the bug reports I filed I ended up editing a text file and saying that sysdiagnose shouldn't be a requirement for bug reports like that, since tech industry best practice is to not require any private information that is not Need to Know (in so many words - I paraphrased). Don't know why Apple is handling it this way. It's so off-putting, it's hard to not read it as a deterrent or deflection.